# Web testing frameworks for ASP.NET web application

Tags: testing, mstest

I'm trying to implement some front end testing in a ASP.NET web application, and I would like to know how do the several web testing frameworks compare. Especially [MSTest's "Web Tests"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182536.aspx), because I haven't seen a lot of info about them, and since it seems to have a nice integration with Visual Studio.

Related posts:
[WatiN or Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417380/watin-or-selenium)
[Watir vs Selenium vs Sahi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606550/watir-vs-selenium-vs-sahi)

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)
[WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/)
[Visual Studio Team System "Web Tests"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182536.aspx)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important thing to note about the Microsoft Web Tests (with VSTS 2008) is that they are at the HTTP level, *not* the UI level.  They'll work great to test navigation, form submission, and other HTTP calls, but will not test the UI components on a page.  This is something important to keep in mind when comparing with other apps such as QuickTest Professional (QTP) which does test at the UI component level.

The much-improved test features of VSTS 2010 *will* include testing at the UI level.

Comment: I was coming to that conclusion myself. Thanks for making it clearer. I guess I won't be needing UI testing, I just need to make sure that changes in the code don't break the workflow of the app.

Comment: I'm trying to conduct UI testing in VSTS 2010 and want to run tests in which I've coded them but I have not found any good documentation or reading material on how to do this. Where can I find some tutorials or how-to's on testing UI?