# What are some alternatives to Selenium?

Tags: java, html, ruby, selenium, automation

What are some web UI automation frameworks available out there?

I know about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426190/selenium-alternatives), but it was asked 3 years ago and things have changed a lot since then. I just wanted to find out if the answers to that question are still relevant or there have been newer and better tools developed since.

I'm asking this again because after doing some googling I've stumbled upon tools such as [Geb](http://www.gebish.org/) and [Capybara](http://jnicklas.github.com/capybara/) that were not mentioned as an answer in that question.

Comment: Below link may helpful for you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122864/selenium-wait-until-document-is-ready

Comment: Thank you for asking this. It's always so risky to ask legitimate questions that aren't narrowly defined with singular and explicit answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WATIR](http://watir.com/) with Cucumber. Infact facebook uses [watir](http://watir.com/) for its UI automation.

Comment: watir is using Selenium under the hood

Answer (score 4):

> there have been newer and better tools developed since.

Take a look at the [TestCafe](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/) testing framework. It runs functional tests in any modern browser and any device. No WebDriver required.

TestCafe is a pure node.js solution.

- It can be easily installed (`npm install -g testcafe` is enough).
- Works without plugins for browsers and additional configuration.
- Write tests in ES6 and ES7 JS syntax.
- Has smart waiting system, so runs async tests fast without extra waiting.
- Can be easily integrated to your CI system.
- Support for running tests on remote machines, devices, and cloud.
- [Free and open source](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe).

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely stick with Selenium, [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) (and Selenium Grid for industrialisation).

If you want something at a slightly lower layer, you can also look at [HtmlUnit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlunit/).

Answer (score 1):

IBM Rational Functional Tester (IE and older firefox builds) or QA Wizard.
RFT runs on Java/Eclipse.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13024991/423955

Answer (score 1):

Sahi (http://sahi.co.in/) should be the best alternative for selenium. One can use java or javascript for the sahi scripts, php and ruby driver is also available (no personal experience with Ruby or php). Very effective with cross browser as well as cross-platform.

Some of the lovable features are: No explicit wait required. For element identification _near, _under, _in etc ApI's are very useful. Logging/Report, feature is inbuilt with Sahi. No Complex configuration required to run the Sahi scripts