# How to make Selenium WebDriver wait for page to load when new page is loaded via JS event

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm working on automating a site which has a number of links which load new pages via a JS event.  Basically, there are elements which are clickable, clicking on one causes some JavaScript to run and this leads to a form being submitted and routing to a new page.

Now if these were just standard HTML links there would be no problem as Selenium is smart enough to tell that there's a new page coming and to wait to do things.  But as good as it is, Selenium can't tell that the clicks in this instance are leading to new pages to load so it doesn't wait and just keeps going.  As such it doesn't wait for the new page, tries to find elements which aren't there and my tests all fail.  Bummer.

As a temporary solution I'm just pausing the program for three seconds like so:

```
oldPageDriver.clickThatButton();

try {
  Thread.sleep(3000);
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}

newPageDriver = new NewPageDriver(driver);
newPageDriver.doStuffOnNewPage();
```

And this works, sort of.  I don't like it because it's "hacky," and just interrupting the program instead of doing something smarter.  Because the delay is hard coded at three seconds I get failures if the link is working but just slow.  I've considered something like an implicit wait but that accomplishes the same thing and I've not found a solid, workable answer in Java anywhere after a considerable amount of looking.

So, can anyone suggest a way around this?  Specifically, how to make Selenium know that a new page is expected and to wait until it's available?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium wait until document is ready](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122864/selenium-wait-until-document-is-ready)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicit waits are what you need;

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

You can directly add this to your test or you may want to DRY it up, especially if there is a common wait expectation such as the disappearance of a spinning icon.

You could extend the click method to always wait after clicking or if following page objects, add a wait_until_loaded method to a base page class.  There many other valid approaches but dependent on how the AUT is implemented

Answer (score 7):

The wait for the document.ready event is not the entire fix to this problem, because this code is still in a race condition: Sometimes this code is fired before the click event is processed so this directly returns, since the browser hasn't started loading the new page yet.

After some searching I found a post on [Obay the testing goat](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html), which has a solution for this problem. The c# code for that solution is something like this:

```
 IWebElement page = null;
 ...
 public void WaitForPageLoad()
 {
    if (page != null)
    {
       var waitForCurrentPageToStale = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
       waitForCurrentPageToStale.Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(page));
    }

    var waitForDocumentReady = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    waitForDocumentReady.Until((wdriver) => (driver as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));

    page = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("html"));

}
```

`
 I fire this method directly after the driver.navigate.gotourl, so that it gets a reference of the page as soon as possible. Have fun with it!

Comment: Perfect, I can not help but say Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Simple *ready2use* snippet, working perfectly for me

```
static void waitForPageLoad(WebDriver wdriver) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(wdriver, 60);

    Predicate<WebDriver> pageLoaded = new Predicate<WebDriver>() {

        @Override
        public boolean apply(WebDriver input) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) input).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }

    };
    wait.until(pageLoaded);
}
```

Comment: Perfect working Java example. In Java 8+ times, it should be noted that this uses com.google.common.base.Predicate, not Java8 native Predicates, but that's a detail.