# Selenium C# Maximum time to wait for Timeout Exception

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

What is the maximum explicit timeout that Selenium C# waits before it throws timeout exception?

Sometimes the application which we are testing becomes very slow and takes up to 4 mins to load .I want to add a wait time, so that it will wait a maximum upto 5 mins.

I have tried with this code

```
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

wait1.Until(x => (bool)((IJavaScriptExecutor)x).ExecuteScript("returnjQuery.active==0"));
```

But it throws timeout exception around 2 mins.

Answer (score 1):

Webdriver has ways for implict and exlict wait but that wont be useful when page is taking too long to load. Also, when an exception or error is occured in the flow, we end up waiting unnecessarily for “specified” time though page has already loaded and nothing is going to change in the remaining time period.

One of the limitation of Webdriver API is no support for WaitForPageLoad out of the box. But we can implement that using WebDriverWait class and readyState property of DOM.

`WebDriverWait` can wait for element. I afraid that `WebDriverWait` won't work on `JavaScriptExecutor` directly. you need to handle something like below

You can wait till document to be in ready state.

```
 string state = string.Empty;
state = ((IJavaScriptExecutor) _driver).ExecuteScript(@"return document.readyState").ToString();
```

The full code be like below

```
public void WaitForPageLoad(int maxWaitTimeInSeconds) {
    string state = string.Empty;
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(maxWaitTimeInSeconds));

        //Checks every 500 ms whether predicate returns true if returns exit otherwise keep trying till it returns ture
        wait.Until(d = > {

            try {
                state = ((IJavaScriptExecutor) _driver).ExecuteScript(@"return document.readyState").ToString();
            } catch (InvalidOperationException) {
                //Ignore
            } catch (NoSuchWindowException) {
                //when popup is closed, switch to last windows
                _driver.SwitchTo().Window(_driver.WindowHandles.Last());
            }
            //In IE7 there are chances we may get state as loaded instead of complete
            return (state.Equals("complete", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || state.Equals("loaded", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

        });
    } catch (TimeoutException) {
        //sometimes Page remains in Interactive mode and never becomes Complete, then we can still try to access the controls
        if (!state.Equals("interactive", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            throw;
    } catch (NullReferenceException) {
        //sometimes Page remains in Interactive mode and never becomes Complete, then we can still try to access the controls
        if (!state.Equals("interactive", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            throw;
    } catch (WebDriverException) {
        if (_driver.WindowHandles.Count == 1) {
            _driver.SwitchTo().Window(_driver.WindowHandles[0]);
        }
        state = ((IJavaScriptExecutor) _driver).ExecuteScript(@"return document.readyState").ToString();
        if (!(state.Equals("complete", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || state.Equals("loaded", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            throw;
    }
}
```

Source :-

https://automationoverflow.wordpress.com/2013/07/27/waiting-for-page-load-to-complete/

Refer below for

[How to make Selenium WebDriver wait for page to load when new page is loaded via JS event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377901/how-to-make-selenium-webdriver-wait-for-page-to-load-when-new-page-is-loaded-via)

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: But in the above code,you have just modified the code which I used. At the end the above code uses webdriver wait with java script.

Comment: updated my answer. You are waiting for returnjQuery.active==0 but here we are waiting to return document.readyState first

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my question is "Does webdriver wait upto 5mins ?" What is the maximum time we can specify as timeout in webdriver wait ? I need answers who is already using it.

Comment: There is no such time limit has been mentioned as per :- https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html...

Comment: You can use Thread.Sleep(5000); , It will halt the execution for 5 min .. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thread.Sleep is the hardcoded wait time but here I am using explicit wait which will wait untill webelement exists.

Answer (score 0):

Answering straight if you are using `ExplicitWait` i.e. `WebDriverWait` while the page gets loaded through:

```
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

wait1.Until(x => (bool)((IJavaScriptExecutor)x).ExecuteScript("returnjQuery.active==0"));
```

**IMO, it's a overhead.**

It is worth to mention that once your script starts loading an url, by default the browser client returns **`document.readyState === "complete"`**. Then only your next line of code gets executed.

### Page Loading:

Now let me get a bit specific now. Using Selenium, by default 3 (three) types of timeouts are implemented as follows:

1. `session script timeout`: Specifies a time to wait for scripts to run. If equal to null then session script timeout will be indefinite. Otherwise it is 30,000 milliseconds.
2. `session page load timeout`: Specifies a time to wait for the page loading to complete. Unless stated otherwise it is 300,000 milliseconds. [**`document.readyState === "complete"`**]
3. `session implicit wait timeout`: Specifies a time to wait in milliseconds for the element location strategy when retreiving elements and when waiting for an element to become interactable when performing element interaction . Unless stated otherwise it is zero milliseconds.

### Element Loading:

In case after an interaction with an element (elementA, which calls a **`jQuery`**) you need to wait for a **`jQuery`** to be completed for another element to be interactable (elementB), the function you mentioned fits the bill.

### Conclusion:

As you are looking for a solution to timeout after 5 mins while loading the url, it is already implemented by default through **`session page load timeout`** with a value **`300,000 milliseconds`** or **`5`** minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ..But in conclusion it is mentioned that,the default wait time is 30,000 ms which is 30s but I am looking for 5mins of Wait time.

Comment: There was a minor typo in the **Conclusion** part, corrected it for further clarity. Please Accept the Answer if it catered to your Question.