# Selenium not waiting for page to load

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing some tests with Selenium, and the tests have to login to a system. This login takes 17 seconds to fully happen.
The system has to wait for it to finish, otherwise the whole test fails.

I've tried many ways to do that, but all of them fail.

First code I've tried was this:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

When I use that, even though I tell it to wait for 100 seconds (which is almost 2 full minutes!), I get a timeout 2 seconds later with this stacktrace.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: timeouts
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'CMTCLX62137', ip: '53.19.227.206', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\ALEX\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.Z2KJE568nWB8, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, moz:headless=false, platform=ANY, proxy=Proxy(manual, http=localhost), specificationLevel=0.0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserVersion=56.0, platformVersion=6.1, moz:processID=21116.0, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=windows_nt}]
Session ID: b2dca4a5-623a-4311-ad07-6444785dbcaf
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteTimeouts.implicitlyWait(RemoteWebDriver.java:868)
```

Another code I've tried:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript(
        "return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
```

Using this, it just doesn't wait and I get a

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element
```

The only way for my test to work is using a Thread.sleep(), but this is a really bad option, because sometimes it loads faster than expected and sometimes it still fails because it takes more than 17s.

Any other option to wait for the page to fully load?

Comment: Selenium always waits until page has been loaded. Please post all code that causes the error so we can investigate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already solved here: [Selenium wait until document is ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122864/selenium-wait-until-document-is-ready)

Anyways I usually wait for controls I need to use, instead of waiting until full page is loaded:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By
            .id(ConfigData.IDs.buttonLogin)));
```

Comment: Sorry, wrong answer comment. This is working. Thank you.

Comment: @IgorÁvila Curious to know what is `ConfigData.IDs` all about. I don't see anything in similar lines in the Question.

Comment: That's just static class I use to store static values used among my project, so I don't need to update all my code when any ID changes, but just in my config class.

Comment: But you have to do this on _every single page_. A global solution would be cleaner

Answer (score 1):

I guess used `elementToBeClickable()` with Explicit wait instead of Page Load

```
WebElement ele= driver.findElement("Locator Value");
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ele));
ele.click();
```

Comment: Still get a "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:" with this code.

Comment: anyway I guess you got the answer.