# Wait for page to load

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create a method that wait for the page to load by `javascript`, but I'm having an error. probably I'm not using the method correctly.

```
public static void WaitForLoad(this IWebDriver driver, int timeoutSec = 15)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, timeoutSec));
        wait.Until(wd => wd.ExecuteJavaScript("return document.readyState") == "complete");
    }
```

The error is:

```
The type arguments for method 'WebdriverExtensions.ExecuteJavaScript<T>(IWerbDriver,string,params object[]' cannot be inferred from the usage.Try specifying the type arguments explicity)
```

Comment: This thread should help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122864/selenium-wait-until-document-is-ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `WaitForLoad(...)` function you are checking for `("return document.readyState") == "complete"`

Practically, the call to the function `WaitForLoad(...)` is purely an overload and have no real effect. That is because *Selenium DLL/JARS/Modules* are designed in such a way that the `webdriver` executes the next line of code only when the *Browser* which you are using sends `document.readyState == "complete"` to the *WebDriver*.

In your case instead of validating  `document.readyState == "complete"` it will be much more effective if we **wait** i.e. induce **ExplicitWait** for the next *WebElement* with which we intend to interact with appropriate clause from either `ElementIsVisible(By)`, `ElementToBeClickable(By)`, `ElementToBeClickable(IWebElement)`, `ElementToBeSelected(IWebElement, Boolean)`, etc.