# Execute script before Dom Ready in Selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How do I run `ExecuteScript` before document ready? The page is already rendered but some scripts that is not relative to the display (such google analytics) are still downloading (and it's very slow).

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.ExecuteScript("window.location='https://veryslowendblockscriptloading.com';"); 
driver.ExecuteScript("alert('bonjour')"); // This line takes forever to load even if it's independent of DOM.
```

I'm using Selenium Webdriver on Chrome 59. 
This behaviour is only on Chrome.

**What I've tried.**

I tried to set  `driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad` to short value (5 seconds) but it looks like webdriver stop loading page (as if i press escape button) when the timeout reached and I don't need this behaviour

It's not a duplicate question as my issue is only on chromedriver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Selenium not wait till full page load, which has a slow script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770796/how-to-make-selenium-not-wait-till-full-page-load-which-has-a-slow-script)

Comment: You can also have a look at [`Don't wait for a page to load using Selenium in Python`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322165/dont-wait-for-a-page-to-load-using-selenium-in-python/46339092#46339092) and [`Wait for page to load`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47130366/wait-for-page-to-load/47131397#47131397)