# How to get selenium to wait for ajax response for XMLHttpRequest based requests

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver and FirefoxDriver to automate an old website. The website was built using plain JavaScript. It is using `XMLHttpRequest` to perform Ajax requests. I want to write a function `WaitForAjax()` that should wait for the Ajax request to complete. Currently, I am using Explicit Wait (`Thread.Sleep`) to accomplish it. Can anyone help me to accomplish the same with Implicit Wait?

```
protected void WaitForAjax() {
    /*  
     while (true) {
         var ajaxIsComplete = (bool)(_driver as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0");
         if (ajaxIsComplete)
             break;
     }
     */

    //I am using Explicit Waits of 3 second.
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122864/selenium-wait-until-document-is-ready  you can try to check ready state of web page

Answer (score 0):

Never use Thread.sleep() unless there is nothing else to do. And in most cases, there is something to do :)
You can try a script like this:

```
public void waitForAjax() {
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = driver -> "complete".equals(((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState"));
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 30);
    wait.until(pageLoadCondition);
}
```

Comment: As I already mentioned that the website I am automating is not using jQuery. Its using XMLHttpRequest to send ajax request.

Comment: Sorry for that, I've edited the method. I'm using java by the way, I saw that you asked for C#, but the idea is same. An explicit wait for an expected condition of "document.readyState"

Comment: thanks for your response. I checked your solution, but document.readyState does not ensure completion of the Ajax request. As per MDN document (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState), document.readyState== 'complete' that the document and all sub-resources have finished loading. It's helpful to check PageLoad. As per this answer(
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/15136386/7875155), there is no generic way of checking the Ajax.

Comment: If you want to wait all asynchronous loads to finish, that's right. There is no way to do that, selenium recommends to use expected conditions for next action.