# How to get visible text from a webpage using Selenium & python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to grab a bunch numbers that are presented in a table on a web page that I’ve accessed using python and Selenium running headless on a Raspberry Pi. The numbers are not in the page source, rather they are deeply embedded in complex html served by several URLs called by the main page (the numbers update every few seconds). I know I could parse the html to get the numbers I want, but the numbers are already sitting on the front page in perfect format all in one place. I can select and copy the numbers when I view the web page in Chrome on my PC.

How can I use python and get Selenium webdriver to get me those numbers? Can Selenium simply provide all the visible text on a page? How? (I've tried `driver.page_source` but the text returned does not contain the numbers). Or is there a way to essentially copy text and numbers from a table visible on the screen using python and Selenium? (I’ve looked into xdotool but didn’t find enough documentation to help). I’m just learning Selenium so any suggestions will be much appreciated!

Comment: What's the HTML look like (e.g. when inspecting via the browser)?  If you can identify the HTML element that contains the text, you can use `.text` to retrieve it.  EG: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-web-driver-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Well, I figured out the answer to my question. It's embarrassingly easy. This line gets just what I need - all the text that is visible on the web page:

`page_text = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text`

Answer (score 0):

So, there are some different situations why you can not get some info on the page:

- Information doesn't loaded yet. You must waiting for some time to get your information ready. You may watch [this theme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15127377/12236467) for the better understanding. Some times you get dynamically added page elements with JS and so on, which loading is very slowly.
- Information may consists of different type of data. For example you are waiting for a text with numbers, but you may get picture with numbers on the page. In this situation you must change your programming tactics and use another functions to get what you need.