# Web Automated Regression Framework

Tags: testing, selenium

I am looking at some options for using a web automated framework.  I have so far looked at Selenium and Web Test (part of Visual Studio), Web Test does not test any client side code, so that kind of rules that one out.  Selenium has most the features needed although I need to generate the .NET code for the tests, so that I can run the tests under TFS build server.

Is selenium the best automated testing web framework, or is there anything else worth looking at that could integrate with .NET and the TFS build.  Ideally I want minimal code changes if any.

Appreciate your thoughts

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been constantly frustrated with Web Test in Visual Studio, though I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say it can't test client side code.

For developer community support, ease of use, and cross platform access, I'd say Selenium is the hands down winner for programmatic browser automation. Selenium 2 works on every major OS/browser and even mobile.

I've tried WaitN and found some bugs in recent version of IE. There was a recent 2.0 release that has probably worked things out, but there are so many more people using Selenium it's worth relying on that community.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I mean is that you can not test any JavaScript using web test

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium can generate C#](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html#programming-languages).  You can use the Selenium libraries in a C# class to create a web UI test library.  Selenium is probably the most common tool.

[Another option is WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/), which is a descendant of Watir for .NET.  It's another web UI automation library

[This StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417380/watin-or-selenium) discusses using the two to test ASP .NET webforms, and might give you a good set of concepts to start from.  My experience with the two is that they were both nice.  I would go with Selenium if working with non-programming testers due to its great record-and-playback tools (for Firefox), and WatiN if working with SDETs / developers due to its richer libraries.  When in doubt, Selenium is more common and more frequently used.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Selenium 2.0 (the C# bindings in particular) / NUnit / Hudson.  Works well, and Selenium 2.0 is constantly improving and working out the remaining bugs