# How to do ASP.NET MVC Integration testing using selenium

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selenium-webdriver, integration-testing, gui-testing

I need to know is it possible to perform integration testing using selenium for ASP.NET MVC applications. If yes then What are the requirements and how to do it. Will it be an external application to test from UI or should I be using views. Really confused. Please guide

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are planning to write the Selenium tests using C#, which I'd recommend over using any kind of test recorder, then this will be a separate project.

You will run this and it will test a deployed version of your application, ideally in a dedicated test environment.  There is [extensive documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/) available.

Personally I and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417380/watin-or-selenium) prefer [WatiN](http://watin.org/) for testing web applications using C# written tests.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can be used for testing any web applications include ASP.NET MVC. In general, you add test project to solution and write tests in it. Selenium open browser and execute commands that is described in your test. You can write test in c# or can use recorder and save record as c# test.