# Completing a form on the internet using Python and downloading a result

Tags: python, html, blast

I'm currently working on a python script and I am stuck.

My script should go on a [webpage](http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PROGRAM=blastn&PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&LINK_LOC=blasthome), upload a file from the computer, fill a form, start an action (BLAST) and then wait since the action can be long. (sometimes one hour). After all this go on a link in the page and download one of the results (Hit table).

I currently just found how to open a webpage from my script but can't find something that would let me "navigate" on the page.

Comment: Why don't you just use the API? http://ncbi.github.io/blast-cloud/dev/api.html

Comment: The output is not the one we seek. And the idea would be that anyone can use it without installing anything thus the script should go on the website and fetch all the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply navigate on a website and simulate user-interaction, you could use [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) [with Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/):

References:

- https://superuser.com/questions/59183/what-can-i-use-to-simulate-user-actions-within-firefox
- [WatiN or Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417380/watin-or-selenium)

Comment: This seems to be interesting, I'm digging in this, keep you up to date if it worked !

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) which allows you to simulate a browser in your script.

Comment: I'll try this too, but for now Selenium seems to work.